# Do I need to worry about timezones in my application?

Tags: date, time, timezone, timestamp

I currently have a functional version of my application (web application). My application allows users to schedule appointments online. When submitting appointments do I need to account for time zones? so if someone lived in new york using my applications which are based in California would I need to make adjustments to the time for which the appointments are getting stored as the date time stamps?

I see UTC all over the web without much understanding if time zone still plays a role in all of this. Can someone guide me as to what approach I need to take for my application?

Thank you for your time! Its very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UTC date is a date/time which is globally the same. Each of the users of your application has a local offset to this date/time, so your application can calculate the correct datetime for each one of your users, based on the UTC date and the offset.

This offset is based on the users location ofcourse, which (depending if you're talking about a web application or desktop or phone app, which you don't mention) might be provided by a browser via JavaScript or through the underlying OS.

So, in short, store all dates as UTC, and calculate the correct date per user to display it in your application.

Most programming languages have functionality for this built-in or available via extensions. Google for "locale" or "Localization" (l10n) in combination with the language or framework you're using to find out how to implement this exactly.

**edit:** you ask specifically about appointments in your application; if your application runs on a webserver, the webservers datetime settings are used, so this might get you into trouble when you compare a datetime from your user to the current time on your server (to see if an appointment is due, for example)

It will also fail when you want to compare an appointment from two users in different timezones to see if they overlap.

If your application only runs locally, without central storage, it will propably work without resorting to UTC datetimes.

Comment: Sorry, my current application is a web application. I really like your response as it gets more detailed as to what I need to do to achieve the goals I am wanting :) thank you for your feedback! :)

Comment: in response to your edit: I see, so if I store the appointment times in UTC this should resolve those server time issues correct? and then of course do localization on the client side for displaying the appointments in the correct time?

Comment: yes. Server side, you can compare the UTC datetimes to check for overlap for example. As soon as you get a (localized) date from your user, convert it to UTC before calculating or storing it. After calculations or fetching UTC dates from storage, convert them to the users locale before displaying. Again, there are extensions and frameworks available that handle most of these conversions for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to properly handle the time zones as the calendar should take the system date as it will be different for different user across the globe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take timezones into account.

If you can adjust the dates and times to UTC, before you transmit and store them, then you will easily be able to compensate for the strangeness of Daylight Saving times.

If you only adjust the UTC times back for display and input, based on your user's locale, then you can schedule across the world.